# keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention gives WARNING: The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call [], but are not present in its tracked objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attention-model

I am builing a keras model with multihead attention layer.
I am trying to implement the MultiHeadAttention layer from keras.layers, but when I run the code, I get the following warning several times on different variables:

"WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.einsum), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
<tf.Variable 'multi_head_attention/query/kernel:0' shape=(1, 8, 240) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer."

The code with which I build my model is as follows:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(25, input_shape=(1, 240), dropout=0.1))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='BinaryCrossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop')
    model.summary()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=1000, shuffle=False, verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

My keras version is 2.4.3. Does anybody have a suggestion how to solve around this warning and whether it is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Warning is of about `tf.keras.layers.Lambda`.
This [blog](https://programming.vip/docs/day-6-tensorflow2-model-subclassing-api.html) states that

> tf.keras.Lambda: Note that if variables are involved in the layer
> created by this method, the variable will not be automatically added
> to the variable set for gradient calculation. Therefore, if there are
> parameters to be trained in the user-defined layer, it is recommended
> to customize the model layer based on the base class

If you are not using keras lambda layer, nothing to worry. Warnings can be ignored.
To suppress the warning use below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
```